# Magento Installation permission issue

Tags: magento, permissions, installation, fedora

I am using Fedora my Os System and was give permission 777 to /var/www/html.

I have try to install magento CE Version 1.9.0.1.But when i am trying to install magento from browser.it show permission issue

```
Path "/var/www/html/magento/app/etc" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/downloadable" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/system" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/system/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/custom" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/custom/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/original" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/original/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/dhl" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/dhl/logo.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/customer" must be writable.
```

using chmod 777 -`R /var/www/html and show same issue`.I thought ,`it can be user permission issue at  /var/www/html/magento/` Can anyone help me ??

Comment: Did you set 777 recursively?

Comment: chmod -R 777  means recursively

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably you have a problem with SELinux permissions. You should try this:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/magento/
chmod -R a+w /var/www/html/magento/
```

Answer (score -6):

Try

chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento

chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento/*

Comment: Global read/write permissions is insecure and never a good idea to set from the root.